# C# How to continue task after receiving a value

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have `async Task` which rotates between 6 players 1 user and 5 bots once it reaches the user's turn it need's to wait for him to press some control after doing so the Task must continue. I was thinking to make it `Task<T>` but I'm not sure how this even works and if it's going to do the job.

```
async Task Turns()
{
    if (!PFturn)
    {
        if (Pturn)
        {
            bRaise.Enabled = true;
            bCall.Enabled = true;
            bRaise.Enabled = true;
            bFold.Enabled = true;
            //await control ?? await result or something like this should be here
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //bots are doing some stuff here
    }
}
```

There are 4 available buttons for the player to press, they all look similar to this one

```
private void bFold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Pturn = false;
    PFturn = true;
}
```

After any of them is pressed the PFturn will equal true so if the program goes back in the `async Task Turns` it will go in to the bot section.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you mean, I'm afraid. A task runs, and when it's completed, it's just done... perhaps you need to use async/await and await "press control" within the async method? (Not sure that's ideal with most event-based UIs, admittedly...)

Comment: Perhaps instead of elaborating verbally, post a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet thanks for your quick response i will update my answer with some of my code this time